# ASP.NET MVC 3 Dropdownlist Helper renders name incorrectly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using the HTML helper for Dropdownlist in the following manner:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("State", new SelectList(states, Model)) %>
```

The control renders fine, with the state items as expected. However, the id and name of the control are not rendering correctly. Instead of name="state" and id="state" I get name="State.State" and id="State_State".

As a result my posted model comes with the State field empty and of course my code fails.

What could cause this to happen, and how might I try to resolve it?

thanks!

Comment: here's some additional info, I have a City property in my model which I'm using a Telerik.AutoCompleteFor and it works properly with the correct id and name.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("State", new SelectList(states, "Id", "Name")) %>
```

where Id and Name must be valid properties of element in the `states` collection you are binding to.